GET /2/tweets/:id/liking_users App Level Rate Limits
Twitter has recently made likes private and GET /2/tweets/:id/liking_users endpoint now requires user-level authorization to retrieve the data of users who liked a tweet. The endpoint has a rate limit of 5 requests per user within a 15-minute window and an overall limit of 25 requests per app within the same period. Since these user-level rate limits are shared across all applications, they don't align well with the needs of my application.
Given these constraints, I want to know if there is a method to check the remaining number of overall requests available for the app and not just for user context ?
